# Parsing of JSON by Codable to array

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have following JSON:

```
[
{
 "id": 1,
 "type": "Feature",
 "geometry": {
     "type": "Point",
     "coordinates": [
         37.5741167,
         55.7636592
     ]
 },
 "properties": {
     "hintContent": "переулок Волков, 13с1",
     "balloonContentHeader": "переулок Волков, 13с1"
 }
]
```

I am trying to use JSONDecoder:

```
struct Point : Codable {
    let id: Int
    let type: String
    let properties: Properties
}
struct Properties : Codable {
    let hintContent: String
    let balloonContentHeader: String
}
struct Points : Codable {
    var data : [Point]
}



func parse(fileName: String) {

    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "json")
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
    if let jsonPoints = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Point].self, from: data!) {
        print(jsonPoints)
    }
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Post your real JSON string. This one is missing a closing curly bracket. Should be `}}
]`

Comment: "What is wrong?"  It's the other way around.  You tell us what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Make sure your JSON is valid -- this one has a missing `}`.
2. Paste your (valid) JSON into app.quicktype.io to generate models ie. make sure that your models match the JSON. In the event that your JSON isn't valid, that site will warn you about it as well.
3. Always use `do/try/catch` and not `try?` so that you can get meaningful errors when JSON decoding fails.

```
let data = """
[
{
 "id": 1,
 "type": "Feature",
 "geometry": {
     "type": "Point",
     "coordinates": [
         37.5741167,
         55.7636592
     ]
 },
 "properties": {
     "hintContent": "t",
     "balloonContentHeader": "t"
 }
}
]
""".data(using: .utf8)

struct Point: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let type: String
    let geometry: Geometry
    let properties: Properties
}

// MARK: - Geometry
struct Geometry: Codable {
    let type: String
    let coordinates: [Double]
}

// MARK: - Properties
struct Properties: Codable {
    let hintContent, balloonContentHeader: String
}

func parse(fileName: String) {
    do {
        let jsonPoints = try JSONDecoder().decode([Point].self, from: data!)
        print(jsonPoints)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    
}
```

Without the adjusted JSON, your original code would generate this error in the `catch` block:

> The given data was not valid JSON....Badly formed object around character 224.

Comment: What's let data = """ ?

Comment: @ElTomato `"""` starts a multi-line String literal in Swift

Comment: @Dmitry did this answer your question? If so, you can mark it is correct using the green checkmark.

Comment: Thanks so much. The issue was other - JSON owner gave in id field intermittently String instead Int. I don't have ideas how to fix this with Codable struct. I had to read each field and check time. But at any case thanks so much. I pushed me to right direction.